# Change background gradient color with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the background gradient color. This is my code. Browser reflects that getColor is undefined.color1, color2 and color 3 are inputs that i get from the user. They work but i am still unable to change the background gradient color.

```
<script>
    function getColor(){
        var color1 = document.getElementById('color1').value;
        var color2 = document.getElementById('color2').value;
        var color3 = document.getElementById('color3').value;
        function getCssValuePrefix()
            {
                var rtrnVal = '';//default to standard syntax
                var prefixes = ['-o-', '-ms-', '-moz-', '-webkit-'];

                // Create a temporary DOM object for testing
                var dom = document.createElement('div');

                for (var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++)
                {
                    // Attempt to set the style
                    dom.style.background = prefixes[i] + 'liner-gradient(#000000, #ffffff)';

                    // Detect if the style was successfully set
                    if (dom.style.background)
                    {
                        rtrnVal = prefixes[i];
                    }
                }

                dom = null;
                delete dom;

                return rtrnVal; 

            }
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = getCssValuePrefix() + 'linear-gradient('+ '38deg' + ', ' + color1 + ', '+ color2  + ',' + color3 +')';

    </script>
```

In html i have a button as follows:

```
<button onclick="getColor">Change Background Color</button>
```

Comment: can you show us the html of the items that have id color1,2 and 3?

Comment: You have `liner-gradient` in your code. That's a typo I believe. Correct it and see if that helps.

Comment: I think you forgot a } at the very end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

> Browser reflects that getColor is undefined

The probable problem is that your script is not placed in `window.onload`. So, the HTML onclick handler tries `getColor` before it's loaded.

Note: You have `liner-gradient` in your code. That's a typo.